# Why select dropdown is returning wrong value?

Tags: javascript, html

the value of the select dropdown is returning wrong value while none of `option` has the value of attribute `selected` is `true`.

Below is the screenshot of chrome console.

[image]

**Edit 1:**
`what` is a `javascript` object of select dropdown.

**Edit 2:**
what looks like in screen as
[image]
and the value of `what` is not initially selected.

Comment: Where is the `what`? The `select` in your screenshot doesn't have that name. Also, did you select that option manually and tried to see what the value is afterwards?

Comment: i have updated my question.

Comment: What does `What` look like on screen? Is any option selected?

Comment: @Rayon sorry i can't provide the jsfiddle for this

Comment: Even though there is no selected `attribute` there can still be a selected `property`. There is a difference between a (HTML) attribute and its corresponding (Javascript) property. Try to output `What.options[17].selected` and `What.options[17].getAttribute('selected')`

Comment: @PraveenRawat – How do we play with the screenshot then ? You can create StackSnippet as well.. Make sure you are not changing the `selected` property somewhere in your `JS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though there is no selected `attribute` there can still be a selected `property`. There is a difference between a (HTML) attribute and its corresponding (Javascript) property.

Try this

```
What.options[17].selected
true

What.options[17].getAttribute("selected")
null
```

A select element with no empty entry will always have one of its options selected automatically, even though you didn't do it manually or by code. In your example, the option 17 has been selected, so it gets the `selected` property set to `true`. For a non-multivalued `select` this will change its value to that of the selected option. Changing a property does *NOT* reflect in the HTML attribute.

The browser will parse the HTML initially. During that parse task it will populate the DOM properties of all the elements found in the process. But changing those properties (manually or automatically) will not change the HTML attributes.